# SceneKit Cast but not Receive Shadows

Tags: scenekit, shadow

Is it possible to have the geometry of an SCNNode cast shadows but not receive them? Currently I've only found the `castsShadow` property to change how a node reacts to shadows.

Comment: Have you resolved it? Meet same problem with you.

Comment: I haven't found a solution, but for the geometry I was using I got some other issues with shadows so I decided to turn them off completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid self-shadowing but keep shadows casted.

```
model.geometry.materials.firstObject.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant;
model.categoryBitMask = 1;
directionalLight.categoryBitMask = ~1UL;
```

> **SCNLightingModelConstant**
>
> Uniform shading that incorporates ambient lighting only.

`SCNLightingModelConstant` only consider ambient light to shading, igonring other visual property.

Then set `categoryBitMask` of model and lights.
If results of bitwise AND of two `categoryBitMask` is zero, node will not take consideration into light illumination, so there no self-shadows anymore. shadows model casted will still remain in scene.

Comment: This will only work for shadowMode SCNShadowModeForward though, correct? How would one achieve this for SCNShadowModeDeferred?